# How can I get source code of specific version of entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, open-source, codeplex

I am using EntityFramework 6.0.0.0 in my project, in my company if we use open source library we need to register it in our system and bring the **original pristine source code** of the library.
What is the easiest way to bring EntityFramework 6.0.0.0 source code.
I tried to find it in [Codeflex source code](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) but it really not easy and I can't find it... someone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to
http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

then change branch by setting

```
Browsing changes in [release -6.1.3-rc1]
```

in this branch you can find the 6.0.0 source code with the release tag `6.0.0`
http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets?page=6

The 6.0.0 changeset http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/9e3591e93e1e59c4a2fdd9ff731986711098101c